# Why is the Probability Generating Function useful to calculate probabilities of the sum of independent variables?

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

I need some help with understanding the purpose of the concept of probability generating functions. The following is the introduction to this concept in my textbook:
"We have found formulae for the mean and variance resulting
from adding independent variables. However, it is also useful to
calculate probabilities of the sum of independent variables. For
discrete variables, we can use a technique called a Probability
Generating Function, which links probability with algebra and
calculus."

Now, suppose that X and Y are discrete random variables (eg following Poisson distribution), which can
only take positive integer values. If the variable Z is their sum
then we can work out the probability that Z = 2. This can be done rather easily as we can find the mean of their sum using the properties of linear combinations of n random variables. Then using Z~Po([mean of X+Y]), we can find P(Z=2). However, if I wanted to use the PGF to find this probability, I would first have to find the probability for every value z and then use the formula G(t)=E(t^Z) to find the PGF of Z, which would take way longer. Hence, I don't understand why "it [the PGF] is also useful to
calculate probabilities of the sum of independent variables."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your distributions do not follow Poisson distribution? In that case, we can't use the result that sum of Independent Poissons distributions gives us another Poisson distributions.

Suppose $X$ follows a certain distribution and $Y$ follows another distribution of which they are independent. The PGF of the $X+Y$ can be obtained by the product of PGF. Sometimes the PGF of $X$ and $Y$ are well known and we don't have to compute from scratch.